# Programaticly Textbox to Gridview without DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a `TextBox` and a `Gridview`.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:Textbox> 

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

Without `DataSource`, how can i add in my .cs file programaticly just TextBox1.Text to Gridview's first column?

```
GridView1.Columns[1].ToString() = TextBox1.Text like that example
```

Comment: Do you want each row to have that value in the first column?

Comment: `GridView1.Columns[1]` refers to the second column, not first

Comment: @Revinder No, Just first column firs row. When i add another Text, it should be first column second row.

Comment: @Alex You are right. But how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a way of processing information when there is no data? If so, you can use the `EmptyDataTemplate` in the GridView and access that programmatically to display the values of your TextBox.

If there is simply no "bound" data to use, the GridView is going to require some kind of data source with at least one entry to function and display properly. However, you can easily add some dummy data in order to enable the functionality of your GridView and then you can tweak it to your heart's content.

Assuming you have a button to initiate the post back (or you can use the OnTextChanged event of your TextBox) simply add the following code.

```
List<string> dummyList = new List<string>(){""};
GridView1.DataSource = dummyList;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

*Note: The list object is just a quick and easy way of using a placeholder for a data source for the GridView. If you really are going to work with multiple columns, I'd recommend creating a simple DataTable with the columns that you will need, insert and empty row, and bind with that. It eliminates the hassle of having to create all of your columns programmatically.*

Then in your GridView's RowDataBound event, you can work with the GridView as much as you like.

```
if (e.Row.RowType -= DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   e.Row.Cells(0).Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this. This will set the first cell of the first row to value of your textbox:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = TextBox1.Text;
```

Remember that columns and rows are accessed with zero-based index, so the first cell of the second row is accessed like this:

```
GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text
```

Comment: I get an error with this code ""Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index""

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Does your GridView actually contain any rows and columns before trying to set any values? Otherwise you might need to create them first.

Comment: I think you are right. GridView will give an exception if you are putting TBox without anything in it.

Comment: GridViews don't exist without a data source! So yeah you need to have data to generate the GridView and *then* append columns as you wish